# Selecting xml node and a value of its' child node based on some criteria in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath

I need to get a node value based on the criteria that another node value meets.

This is the xml example that I am searching through:

```
<Elements>
<Element>
    <ElementID>A1</ElementID>
    <ElementName>Element A</ElementName>
    <ElementValues>
        <ElementValue>
            <ValueText>A Value</ValueText>
            <ValueDescription>A Type Element</ValueDescription>
        </ElementValue>
    </ElementValues>
</Element>
<Element>
    <ElementID>B1</ElementID>
    <ElementName>Element B</ElementName>
    <ElementValues>
        <ElementValue>
            <ValueText>B Value</ValueText>
            <ValueDescription>B Type Element</ValueDescription>
        </ElementValue>
    </ElementValues>
</Element>
</Elements>
```

I need a tag value from the ValueText tag from the node with certain ElementID. For example: if the search criteria is "A1", than the result should be "A Value". (something like: **get ValueText.Value if ElementID = "A1"**)
Please help me with this one (Linq, XPath, whatever...), I'm just spinning in the circles and getting nowhere.

Thanks in advance!

I really have searched for the answer, but couldn't get the similar one...

Answer (score 2):

If I am right, you can use the XPath expression

```
//Element[ElementID/text() = \"B1\"]
```

It will search for every `<Element>` node in the XML document and select those who have an `<ElementID>` subnode which additionally has the property that `text()`(the inner text) has a value of `B1`. You can modify the "B1" to "A1" and you will get the other node, just be carefull when inserting user input in there, you don't want them to be able to modify your complete XPath expression, which can lead to vulnerabilites.

Here's a sample program.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xml = @"<Elements>
                    <Element>
                        <ElementID>A1</ElementID>
                        <ElementName>Element A</ElementName>
                        <ElementValues>
                            <ElementValue>
                                <ValueText>A Value</ValueText>
                                <ValueDescription>A Type Element</ValueDescription>
                            </ElementValue>
                        </ElementValues>
                    </Element>
                    <Element>
                        <ElementID>B1</ElementID>
                        <ElementName>Element B</ElementName>
                        <ElementValues>
                            <ElementValue>
                                <ValueText>B Value</ValueText>
                                <ValueDescription>B Type Element</ValueDescription>
                            </ElementValue>
                        </ElementValues>
                    </Element>
                    </Elements>";
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xml);
        XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;

        /* Select all "<Element>" nodes which have an <ElementID> subnode where the text equals "B1". */
        var nodes = root.SelectNodes("//Element[ElementID/text() = \"B1\"]");

        foreach(XmlNode node in nodes){
            Console.WriteLine("Found matching Element: \n {0}", node.InnerXml);
        }
  }
```

Outputs

```
Found matching Element: 
 <ElementID>B1</ElementID><ElementName>Element B</ElementName><ElementValues><ElementValue><ValueText>B Value</ValueText><ValueDescription>B Type Element</ValueDescription></ElementValue></ElementValues>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straightforward LINQ query:

```
string xml = ...;
var root = XElement.Parse(xml);
string elementID = "A1";
var result = root.Elements("Element")
    .Where(e => e.Element("ElementID").Value == elementID)
    .Select(e => e.Element("ElementValues").Element("ElementValue").Element("ValueText").Value)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with XML and LINQ to XML provides an object oriented approach of working with XML. For example, when the XML is initially parsed, the entire XML strucutre is the object, i.e., the Root. When selecting nodes, each node becomes it's own object. From your example, assuming you already have the XML is a string (could be a file, or stream, whatever):

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

// retrieve the parent node of A1
XElement a1 = doc.Root.Elements("Element")
                      .First(x => x.Element("ElementID").Value == "A1");

// a1 now has an XML structure of:
// <Element>
//   <ElementID>A1</ElementID>
//   <ElementName>Element A</ElementName>
//   <ElementValues>
//     <ElementValue>
//       <ValueText>A Value</ValueText>
//       <ValueDescription>A Type Element</ValueDescription>
//     </ElementValue>
//   </ElementValues>
// </Element>

// get the value of ValueText w/ a verbose path:
string verbosePath = a1.Element("ElementValues")
                       .Element("ElementValue")
                       .Element("ValueText").Value;

// alternatively, short-circuit the path:
string shortPath = a1.Descendants("ValueText").First().Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Done with LINQ, replace `elementId` with the element id you want the value text of.

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var elements = xDoc.Element("Elements");
var element = elements.Elements("Element").Single(e => e.Element("ElementID").Value.Equals(elementId));
var valueText = element.Descendants("ValueText").Single().Value;
```